# Как публиковать проект asp.net mvc5 на веб сервер iis

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

у меня есть вопрос помогите пожалуйста, я создал проект на asp.net mvc5, и теперь для тестирования мы с коллегами хотим ее запустить каждый на своем компьютере но для этого я должен поднять веб сервер, я пытаюсь поднять на iis но не выходит вместо проекта он показывает каталог проекта помогите пожалуйста заранее спасибо!

Comment: [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: [Publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)